# What is "group" property for in Gradle?

Tags: groovy, gradle

[`Gradle` documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project%3agroup)  lists `group` as a property of `Project`.

I failed to find any hints about the **purpose** and/or **usage** of this property.

Please point me into the right direction.

Answer (score 26):

`group` signifies the `groupId` of the project/task that is being worked on.

```
com.example:my-project:0.1
----------- ---------- ---
     |         |        |
   groupId  artifact  version
```

Comment: What are the benefits of assigning a value to `group` in `build.gradle`?

Comment: The same benefit we get having packages for classes. This helps is customizing maven artifact.

Comment: Will this [line from `build.gradle` in `groovy-core`](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/build.gradle#L37) be adequate or should I be more specific?

Comment: You compared groups with packages for classes.  Packages in addition to grouping multiple classes together at the same logical location, also impact visibility levels of class variables. Do groups have secondary functions of any sort?  Also, are they strictly for use with Maven?

Comment: Mainly grouping is the point of concern here. It would differ from package when you pointed out visibility levels. Take for example, grails plugins, the default group for grails plugins is `org.grails.plugins`. They are not strictly use with Maven (as a build tool). They follow the Maven artifact definifion, so that it can be referred from maven central repo. Does it help?

Comment: Using analogy with packages again,.  Package statement declares that every class in this source code file belongs to the package.  What about group?

Comment: Yes, every artifact under that group belongs to that group.

Comment: Well... I have a `Gradle` script that works fine with or without group assignment.  Is there a case when assigning value to the `group` is absolutely necessary? I'm asking about cases when I create my own script and do not plan to upload it anywhere for sharing.

Comment: You can go through [Maven Naming Convention](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html), if that helps. :)